# How to upgrade to a newest build version my installed MySQL on Debian?

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I am using Debian and I have MySQL 5.1.57 installed. I know that there is a newer version available: 5.1.61. How can I do the upgrade? Also, can I do the upgrade with MySQL online, or do I have to bring it down?

Thanks in advance
Panayotis

Comment: which Debian version are you running? And are you using the packages from the apt repositories or did you download a *.deb package from mysql?

Comment: @klennepette Good questions: Debian 6. I am using apt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To upgrade you can use the command `aptitude upgrade mysql-server` This will upgrade your mysql server to the latest version **for your version of Debian** and will **automatically restart** your MySQL server.

You can see [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/mysql-server) which version will be installed, the link goes to Squeeze but you can select other versions too. These are not necessarily the latest versions of MySQL though.

It's a good idea to run `aptitude update` before upgrading to update the packages list in case it's outdated.

Comment: I will accept your answer, because this explains the usage of the standard ```apt``` package manager in ```Debian```. It also tells me about its limitations, meaning I cannot upgrade to ```5.1.61``` since this is not in any of the Debian packages. Since I am using ```wheezy```, I followed your procedure to upgrade from ```5.1.57``` to ```5.1.58``` (at least).

Answer (score 2):

My advice is that you do a [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) on your current database, install the new version and restore the dump from the old database to the new installed version.

It's safer to dump and restore it then updating and lose stored data.

But, [Upgrading MySQL on Debian](http://www.laurenwood.org/anyway/2005/02/upgrading-mysql-on-debian/) may be the approach you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for answer. The question is about the recommended way to **install** the new version. Is it with **apt-get**? And if **yes** what are the details? How do I do it? What are the commands to do it?

Comment: It's safer to install it manually. You may lose stored data. Install the new version with apt-get and restore the dump. Here's a [link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/) that describes mysqldump much easier

Comment: I will say again, in another way: The backup is not my problem. The problem is with going MySQL from version 5.1.57 to version 5.1.61. I know how to take backup. Do you know how to do this small upgrade on Debian 6?

Comment: This person describes [how to upgrade MySQL in Debian](http://www.laurenwood.org/anyway/2005/02/upgrading-mysql-on-debian/). Which Debian version is unknown, though :S

Comment: It does not work. I tried that. This is a very old post. It may used to work the time it was written.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise ?

Will you upgrade your mysql version by a debian tool, such as aptitude or apt ?

or you will download and install a new fresh copy by yourself ?

in this case, you should be able to run the both 2 versions in the same time.

dumping old one to new one and then switch from the old to the new.

if using debian tools, I imagine this is done "automagically" but you will get offline while replacing.

Comment: I am using Debian apt. I do not want to do it manually the way you describe. Do you know how to do that with Debian apt?